# Texture as color variation

Tags: expresso-store

I have products with different texture patterns ( See attached #patterns). [ I am using EE 2.7.0 + Expresso store 2.0.3. ]
I want these texture patterns as variation.

Configuration:

Channel: Products [ product ]
Channel Fields: Specification [ specification ] 
                - Modifier type : Variation
                - Name : texture
                - Options : adobe, sephia, ...etc

Now through these options or any other way I want thumb to display for each variation.

Thanks,
Parth

## patterns

[image]

Comment: Are the textures the same or different for each product?

Answer (score 2):

Set your options names the same as the image filename (without extension) and use that to pull the image.

```
{exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" return="/checkout/basket"}
  {modifiers}
    {if "{modifier_name}" == "texture"}
      {modifier_options}
        <img src="your-path-to-images/{option_name}.jpg"/>
      {/modifier_options}
    {/if}
  {/modifiers}
{/exp:store:product}
```

I've not done the correct html for radio buttons and labels with images, but you get the idea.

You need to set the value for the form elements as the `{option_id}` for Store to be able to understand it.

If you have Colour/Color ;) labelling with spaces or want capitalisation and don't want to worry about it for filenaming, then you can use the `{option_id}` as the filename instead.

[Docs](https://exp-resso.com/docs/product_tag.html#modifiers_variable_pair)